# Help Understanding Etale Space of Sheaf (Local Homeomorphism)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am new to algebraic geometry. I can't understand why an etale space is considered locally homeomorphic to its base space. The analogy I have heard is that etale space can be visualized as "stacked over" the base space, or that it is like a "puff pastry". I understand that we can (locally) map this stacked/pastry space to the base space, but I don't understand how an inverse map could exist. It seems to me like the inverse map would be multi-valued as it takes a point in the base space to several points in the etale space.

As an example, consider the base space to be a circle and an etale space to be a circle winding around itself twice. The map from the etale space takes two points to one point of the circle. Doesn't this mean that the inverse map is multi-valued?

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misinterpreting this. The claim is that for all points in the etale space, there exists an open neighborhood so that the projection restricted to that neighborhood is a homeomorphism. For instance, if you take a small interval on the circle winding twice, it's image is again a small interval of the target circle, and the projection map restricted to this small interval is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Scorpio. That makes sense to me. However, in the book that I am reading it says the following: "Let E be an etale space and p a local homeomorphism. The fiber over x is the set E_x which is equal to p^-1(x)."  I still don't understand what is meant by p^-1(x) though. What is the image of p^-1(x)?

Comment: That's the inverse image of $x$ under the map $p$; they're not defining an inverse map to $p$. (By the way, [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) works in the comments.)

Comment: Thank you! I think I get it now. The -1 exponent is just meant to indicate the preimage of the map. It's not exactly an inverse of the local homeomorphism. Perhaps one would call it an abuse of notation or something.

Comment: I would not call it an abuse of notation, it's the standard way to refer to the inverse image of a point under a map. If this answers your question, please consider "accepting" the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).